# PHP to add elements in existing html document

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic

I want to use html form and submit so I can have

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$content = $_POST["content"];
```

to use in this "pattern"

```
<div class="event-tobe" data-date="MONTH-DAY-YEAR">
    <span class="dateDay">VISIBLE_DAY</span>
    <span class="dateMonth">VISIBLE_MONTH</span>
    <h2><a href="generated.html">HEADLINE</a></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
```

and then I want to insert that whole div in the another existing html file

I don't need database entries to save data, I need it in the .html document so it can be "seen" as a new event

Is it possible to do that with PHP or I should go for another solution?

Comment: Well for a start, you would need to use a `server-side` language, such as `PHP`, or `ASP.NET` for example to `POST` the data, and save it in a database.

Comment: thank you for your time, can javascript alter html in another html file and can it generate a new file? @NickR

Comment: No it can't generate a file, because it's client side, you need a `server` side language to create files.

Comment: Thank you very much, you saved me alot of time

Comment: I changed the question so that it makes some sense, I also scouted some php but I can't find the solution. Thx @NickR

Comment: This question has been reopened. Thank you for taking the time to create good questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form on the page like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<form action="." method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="date" />
    <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You can have a PHP block on the page that detects whether the form has been submitted:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Inside it, you can display your custom HTML with the values in the form fields:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php if(isset($_GET['submit'])) { 
    // process date
    $theDate = strtotime($_GET["date"]);
?>
    <div class="event-tobe" data-date="<?= date('m-d-Y', $theDate) ?>">
        <span class="dateDay"><?= date('d', $theDate) ?></span>
        <span class="dateMonth"><?= date('m', $theDate) ?></span>
        <h2><a href="generated.html"><?= $_GET["name"] ?></a></h2>
        <p><?= $_GET["content"] ?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```